# Why am I getting 404 error when performing Delete?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Controller code:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
public class RuleController : Controller
{
    public IRuleRepository RuleRepo { get; set; }

    // http://localhost:58307/api/Rule/Delete/3186
    // error 404
    [HttpDelete("{id}")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
    {
        await RuleRepo.Remove(id);
        return NoContent();
    }
    
    // http://localhost:58307/api/Rule/GetById/3186
    // works as expected
    [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetRules")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetById(int id) //this action works
    {
        var item = await RuleRepo.Find(id);
        if (item == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(item);
    }
```

Web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I reviewed this question and can't tell if I'm "mixing routes" or not.

[ASP.NET CORE Web API - delete action not firing (404 not found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44218133/asp-net-core-web-api-delete-action-not-firing-404-not-found)

Comment: Update your controller route to `[Route("api/[controller]")]`and call the method with `Delete` HttpVerb. Also don't pass the Action name `Delete` in the url

Comment: Can you show how you're calling the endpoint?

Comment: What you have is valid, you shouldn't have to change to `[Route("api/[controller]")]` to make it work, so what @SowmyadharGourishetty is saying is not necessarily the solution, I think you should show how do you create your call to that API endpoint

Comment: @Fabooo, That might not be the solution, but having the `[action]` at the controller level right?

Comment: [action] at your controller level just mean that you have to specify the name of the action on your call, example: `http://localhost:50830/api/rule/delete/1` so having `[action]` at the controller level is not your real issue

Answer (score 2):

I updated controller route to `[Route("api/[controller]")]` and used Fiddler to call `[DELETE] localhost:58307/api/Rule/3185` and it was successful.

Credit to sowmyadhar-gourishetty for the answer.

Comment: And that right there is part of what RESTFul is all about: using HTTP VERBs to operate on resources.

Comment: @CodingYoshi what?